# How to check if three column values of a dataframe are less than simultaneous values of another standard dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a standard dataframe template `df1`:

```
a = [['100', '20', '20'], ['150', '60', '80'], ['200', '100', '100'],['500', '50', '100']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

```
df1
Out[50]: 
     A    B    C
0  100   20   20
1  150   60   80
2  200  100  100
3  500   50  100
```

and my dataset `df2`

```
b = [['180.5', '60.3', '20.2'], ['40.2', '2.2', '33.9'], ['205', '100', '100'],['455', '20', '88'],['100', '60', '130'],['10', '10', '10'],['300.64', '66.4', '29.4']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['A1', 'B1', 'C1'])
```

```
df2 
       A1    B1    C1
0   180.5  60.3  20.2
1    40.2   2.2  33.9
2     205   100   100
3     455    20    88
4     100    60   130
5      10    10    10
6  300.64  66.4  29.4
```

I want to iterate value of A1,B1,C1 of `df2` against all simultaneous values of `df1` and append only that set of values to my `df2` where all 3 conditions are satisfied (A1<=A, B1<=B, C1<=C).
If the conditions are satisfied for multiple rows in `df1`, then I will just need the first set of standard value.

This may be considered as checking if all 3 dimensions are within any available standard dimension template.

Expected Output for my dataset `df2`:

```
       A1    B1    C1      A      B      C
0   180.5  60.3  20.2  200.0  100.0  100.0
1    40.2   2.2  33.9  150.0   60.0   80.0
2     205   100   100    NaN    NaN    NaN
3     455    20    88  500.0   50.0  100.0
4     100    60   130    NaN    NaN    NaN
5      10    10    10  100.0   20.0   20.0
6  300.64  66.4  29.4    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Could not find any suitable solution. I tried with lists but could not come any closer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`Numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
df1 = df1.astype(float)
df2 = df2.astype(float)

m = (df2.values[:, None] <= df1.values).all(-1)
df2 = df2.join(df1.iloc[m.argmax(1)].set_axis(df2.index)[m.any(1)])
```

#### Explanations

We can use `broadcasting` to create a boolean mask by comparing each row in `df2` to every other row in  `df1`, then reduce this boolean mask with `all` along `axis=-1`

```
>>> m

array([[False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

Now, use `argmax` along `axis=1` on mask `m` to find the indices of first max value in each row where all the conditions `A1<=A, B1<=B, C1<=C` are satisfied

```
>>> m.argmax(1)

array([2, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0])
```

Select the rows from `df1` corresponding to the above indices with the help of `iloc` and conform the index of these selected rows with the index of `df2`

```
>>> df1.iloc[m.argmax(1)].set_axis(df2.index)

       A      B      C
0  200.0  100.0  100.0
1  150.0   60.0   80.0
2  100.0   20.0   20.0
3  500.0   50.0  100.0
4  100.0   20.0   20.0
5  100.0   20.0   20.0
6  100.0   20.0   20.0
```

Now filter the rows from the above selected rows such that they satisfies the given condition `A1<=A, B1<=B, C1<=C` and `join` the filtered rows to to `df2`

```
>>> df2

       A1     B1     C1      A      B      C
0  180.50   60.3   20.2  200.0  100.0  100.0
1   40.20    2.2   33.9  150.0   60.0   80.0
2  205.00  100.0  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  455.00   20.0   88.0  500.0   50.0  100.0
4  100.00   60.0  130.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
5   10.00   10.0   10.0  100.0   20.0   20.0
6  300.64   66.4   29.4    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I am somehow getting an ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable``` after the code edit. Could you specifiy the reason?

Comment: @axay Can you please show the full stacktrace of error message? Is the code before the edit working fine for you?

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-1151e8aee9d3>", line 1, in <module>
    df2[['A', 'B', 'C']] = df1.iloc[m.argmax(1)].set_axis(df2.index)[m.any(1)]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: @axay You need to set the optional parameter  `inplace=False` in the `set_axis` method like this `.set_axis(df2.index, inplace=False)` because in pandas version `0.25.1` the default value of `inplace` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

First use `cross` join by all values, then filter by conditions, remove duplicates by `index` value and add to `df2` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
#input data ar strings, so convert to numbers
df1 = df1.astype(float)
df2 = df2.astype(float)

df = pd.merge(df2.reset_index(), df1, how='cross')

df = (df[(df.A1<=df.A) & (df.B1<=df.B) & (df.C1<=df.C)]
      .drop_duplicates('index')
      .set_index('index')[df1.columns])
print (df)
           A      B      C
index                     
0      200.0  100.0  100.0
1      150.0   60.0   80.0
3      500.0   50.0  100.0
5      100.0   20.0   20.0

df = df2.join(df)
print (df)
       A1     B1     C1      A      B      C
0  180.50   60.3   20.2  200.0  100.0  100.0
1   40.20    2.2   33.9  150.0   60.0   80.0
2  205.00  100.0  100.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
3  455.00   20.0   88.0  500.0   50.0  100.0
4  100.00   60.0  130.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
5   10.00   10.0   10.0  100.0   20.0   20.0
6  300.64   66.4   29.4    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I am getting merge error: ```MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on.``` Could you brief why is this so? @jezrael

Comment: @axay - What is your pandas version?

Comment: ```'0.25.1'``` is there any version issue?

Comment: @axay - Exactly, need last version of pandas.